# Getting System.InvalidCastException while loading View from a xib file

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, xib, nsview

I have a xib file - LoaderView.xib and associated class LoaderView.cs which contains a view for showing loading text. When I try to load it in the main ViewController as -

```
public override void ViewDidAppear()
{
   base.ViewDidAppear();

   NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNibNamed("LoaderView", this, out NSArray arr);
   var view = Runtime.GetNSObject<LoaderView>(arr.ValueAt(0));
   view.Frame = View.Frame;
   View.AddSubview(view);
}
```

I am getting the System.InvalidCastException in this line -

```
var view = Runtime.GetNSObject<LoaderView>(arr.ValueAt(0));
```

And the strange part is I do not get the exception every time. When it works, I am seeing the loading text overlapped with default view - associated with the ViewController.

[image]

Can someone point out what is the best way to show Loading, Error and Empty states. Should I have separate ViewControllers for them? Or Can I have separate xib files which I can load/unload from the main View Controller? How to load a view from a xib file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies within arr.

[image]

[image]

In the above images, it can be seen that somehow the method `LoadNibNamed` is not returning the top level objects in `arr` in the same sequence every time. That's why the code -

```
var view = Runtime.GetNSObject<LoaderView>(arr.ValueAt(0));
```

is not able to cast the 0th item of `arr` to type `LoaderView` every time.

The solution is to traverse the array to find the item of your type - `LoaderView` here. For my case -  I wrote a static class which has a generic method `LoadViewFromNib` which returns a view of type T inheriting from `NSView`.

```
public static class LoadNib
{
    static NSArray xibItems;
    static nuint index;


    public static T LoadViewFromNib<T>(string filename, NSObject owner) where T : NSView
    {
        NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNibNamed(filename, owner, out xibItems);

        for (nuint i = 0; i < xibItems.Count; i++)
        {
            NSObject item = xibItems.GetItem<NSObject>(i);
            if (item is T)
            {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        return Runtime.GetNSObject<T>(xibItems.ValueAt(index));
    }
}
```

And as for the overlapping issue, I found out that a subview is transparent unless its background is set explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a documentation problem with Xamarin. Their documentation says to use the 0th index, but the reality is that the array order isn't deterministic.

The answer Anagh gives is sufficient and technically most optimal, but you can make it more succinct by using Linq and it also lends itself fairly well to an extension method:

```
public static class NibLoadingExtension
{
    public static T LoadViewFromNib<T>(this T @null) where T : NSView
    {
        NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNibNamed(typeof(T).Name, null, out var array);
        return NSArray.FromArray<NSObject>(array).OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, since you can't call extension methods in C# without an instance, you have to use it like this:

```
var loaderView = default(LoaderView).LoadViewFromNib();
```

There is also an argument to be made in favor of adding a static Create() method or something to each individual view class, because then you can call a private initializer, like so:

```
public static LoaderView Create(ExampleDependency dependency)
{
    var model = dependency ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dependency));
    NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNibNamed(nameof(LoaderView), null, out var array);
    var view = NSArray.FromArray<NSObject>(array).OfType<LoaderView>().FirstOrDefault();
    view.Initialize(model);
    return view;
}

private void Initialize(ExampleDependency dependency)
{
    _privateField1 = dependency.Value1;
    _privateField2 = dependency.Value2;
    _privateField3 = dependency.Value3;
}
```